# Jquery lightbox for videos is not working on Google Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, lightbox

i am using jquery lightbox in grails project. It working fine in firefox, IE 8,9,10 and safari browsers. But it is not working for Google Chrome.

anybody have idea?

Comment: without an example it's very hard to predict what's happening in your project